# Change a html class with javascript in my php model?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using this simple PHP framework: https://github.com/panique/mini

I have a foreach loop in my model and I want to change a html tag in my view before and after the loop.

I have tested this in my model and its not working so well

```
public function myFunction()
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">$( ".disable" ).addClass("disable-color"); $(".disable").bind("click", false);</script>';

foreach ($arr as $value) {
//some stuff
}
//echo javascript again to change back the html class
}
```

I display data from the database through my model when the user presses a button in my view. I want to change the color of the button when I get data from the database (in my foreach) and change back the color when I received all the data

How should I do this? Change a html class in my view before and after a foreach in my model?

Comment: Can u explain - what exactly u want at finish, mb it can be solved by ajax?

Comment: I display data from the database through my model when the user presses a button in my view. I want to change the color of the button when I get data from the database (in my foreach) and change back the color when I received all the data.

Comment: if u show all code - i can try to write answer more understandable

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed on the server, Javascript is executed in the browser.

So, first you're PHP does all it's work, then the result of that is sent to the browser, and only then Javascript get's its turn to do stuff.

So you cannot intermingle the two.

I cannot tell you how you should do, what you want to do, in another way, because it is unclear what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In example.php - u have request, what get `$_GET['rid']` and make request to db with `$_GET['rid']`, then it return result to `.done`

```
array = [1,2,3,foo,foo2] //ur array for request to db.
array.each(function( index, value ) {
  $.get( "example.php?rid="+value, function() {
  // change color to before get from db
})
  .done(function(data) {
    // change color to after get from db
  })
});
```

in .done at data - u have ans from ur server